# Retrieve a ComboBox counts and items by using SendMessage API

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, winapi, combobox

I want to get a count and list of `ComboBox` control which is not mine so that I cannot modify the code.

For example, controlling the target app can be done by using `SendMessage` API.

But, how can I retrieve a whole list of the target control by hooking?

Comment: You can use UI Automation

Comment: [GetComboBoxInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775939(v=vs.85).aspx) and use `hwndList` from [COMBOBOXINFO](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775798(v=vs.85).aspx) ?

Comment: You have interleaved your proposed solution into your problem description. Please ask about the problem you are trying to solve only. That means removing all references to *"`SendMessage`"* and *"hooking"*.

Comment: In win32 C++ we can get count by `int n = SendMessage(comboBox1, CB_GETCOUNT, 0, 0); `

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find a list of `ComboBox` control messages here:

- [MSDN - ComboBox Control Messages](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff485901.aspx)
- [PInvoke - CB_ Constants](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Constants/CB_.html)

To get items count you need to use [`CB_GETCOUNT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775841(v=vs.85).aspx) message and to get text of an item you can use [`CB_GETLBTEXT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775862(v=vs.85).aspx) message.

**Example**

Here I created a `ComboBoxHelper` class which you can create its instance by passing `Handle` of the `ComboBox` and use its properties:

- `SelectedIndex` as `Integer`: Returns selected index, returns -1 if no item is selected.
- `Selectedtext` as `String`: Returns text of selected item, returns `String.Empty` if no item is selected.
- `ItemsCount` as `Integer`: returns count of items.
- `Items(index)` as `String`: returns text of specified item (the item at specified index)
- `Items` as `List(of String)`: returns the list of items of combo box. If there is no items, it returns an empty list.

```
Public Class ComboBoxHelper
    Private hWnd As IntPtr
    Const CB_GETCURSEL As Integer = &H147
    Const CB_SETCURSEL As Integer = &H14E
    Const CB_GETCOUNT As Integer = &H146
    Const CB_GETLBTEXT As Integer = &H148
    Const CB_GETLBTEXTLEN As Integer = &H149
    <System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")> _
    Shared Function SendMessage(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal Msg As Integer, _
        ByVal wParam As Integer, ByRef lParam As Integer) As IntPtr
    End Function
    <System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")> _
    Shared Function SendMessage(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal Msg As Integer, _
        ByVal wParam As Integer, ByVal lParam As System.Text.StringBuilder) As IntPtr
    End Function
    Public Sub New(handle As IntPtr)
        hWnd = handle
    End Sub
    Public Property SelectedIndex As Integer
        Get
            Return SendMessage(hWnd, CB_GETCURSEL, 0, 0).ToInt32()
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            SendMessage(hWnd, CB_SETCURSEL, value, 0).ToInt32()
        End Set
    End Property
    Public ReadOnly Property ItemsCount As Integer
        Get
            Return SendMessage(hWnd, CB_GETCOUNT, 0, 0).ToInt32()
        End Get
    End Property
    Public ReadOnly Property SelectedText As String
        Get
            Dim index = Me.SelectedIndex
            If (Me.SelectedIndex = -1) Then
                Return String.Empty
            End If
            Return Me.Items(index)
        End Get
    End Property
    Public ReadOnly Property Items() As List(Of String)
        Get
            If (ItemsCount > 0) Then
                Return Enumerable.Range(0, ItemsCount) _
                                 .Select(Function(index) Items(index)).ToList()
            Else
                Return New List(Of String)
            End If
        End Get
    End Property
    Public ReadOnly Property Items(index As Integer) As String
        Get
            If (index < 0 OrElse index >= ItemsCount) Then
                Throw New ArgumentOutOfRangeException("index")
            End If
            Dim length = SendMessage(hWnd, CB_GETLBTEXTLEN, index, 0).ToInt32()
            Dim text As New System.Text.StringBuilder(length)
            SendMessage(hWnd, CB_GETLBTEXT, index, text)
            Return text.ToString()
        End Get
    End Property
End Class
```

Here is an example of usage of the class:

```
Dim combo As New ComboBoxHelper(hWnd) 'You have hWnd
MessageBox.Show(combo.ItemsCount.ToString())
MessageBox.Show(combo.SelectedIndex.ToString())
MessageBox.Show(combo.SelectedText.ToString())
combo.Items.ForEach(Function(item) MessageBox.Show(item))
```

Comment: You cannot send `CB_GETLBTEXT` across process boundaries (or any window class private message for that matter). Sorry, not a solution. -1.

Comment: @IInspectable Don't be too hurried to downvote answers. First test them. I tested it using two different processes and it works properly :)

Comment: @IInspectable You can simply test it using 2 different applications, one contained the combobox, and another used my `ComboBoxHelper` to get items text and count. After you test it, cast an upvote if you liked the answer. I'll save a dummy change in the answer to let you to change your vote ;)

Comment: Ah, that's true. `CB_GETLBTEXT` **is** indeed a standard Windows message (not a `WM_USER` message). Anyway, still a poor solution. Use UI Automation instead, to be able to read contents of combo boxes, that aren't backed by native windows.

Comment: @IInspectable Yes, it's a standard combo box message which is addressed here: [ComboBox Control Messages](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff485901.aspx). The answer seems to be useful for future readers, isn't it? ;)

Comment: @IInspectable Yes, it can be done using UIAutomation, it also can be a valuable answer for this question.

Comment: This answer may be useful to future readers, not brave enough to adventure into a robust solution (UI Automation). The fact the `CB_GETLBTEXT` is a standard combo box message is not relevant. What is important is, that it is a standard Windows message. `TVM_INSERTITEM` is a standard tree view message, but not a standard Windows message, and it doesn't automatically marshal its parameters across process boundaries. So you were right, because you were lucky. Not because you know.

Comment: @IInspectable If you have a valuable knowledge to share it's enough to share it, you don't need to prove what you know or what other doesn't know. Anyway, your comment can be useful for future readers :)